# Deploy SharePoint 2013 on Azure for Learning

Tags: 2013, azure

I wish to learn SharePoint 2013 in & out from administration perspective.
Thus planning to deploy it on Azure, as it provides flexibility to access the Virtual Machine from anywhere.

Thus looking for information on deployment articles.
Any pointer will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below articles which covers end to end for configuring and managing SharePoint farms on Azure VM's.

[Reference-1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn275958.aspx)

[Reference-2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-sharepoint-farm-azure-preview/)